# Как получить значение клетки из таблицы?

Tags: jtable, java, swing

Как получить значение клетки (i;j) из таблицы JTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От таблицы надо вызвать метод getModel(), который вернёт вам модель таблицы, а от него уже вызвать метод getValueAt(i, j), который и вернёт вам требуемый элемент.
Однако если у вас применяется сортировка, фильтрация или нечто подобное, нужно преобразовать индексы методами convertRowIndexToModel() и convertCollumnIndexToModel() перед вызовом getValueAt(), иначе можно получить совершенно другие значения. Есть методы обратного преобразования - convertRowIndexToView() и convertCollumnIndexToView(), которые применяются, если не ошибаюсь, для программного выбора строки.

Comment: Вы если человеку отвечаете, отвечайте полнее. Ибо если View таблицы будет изменен, то ТС получит не те значения, которых ожидал, и придется передавать в качестве параметров результаты методов, которые конвертируют индексы представления/модели. Разницы нет только если представление отображает модель как есть без фильтрации, перемены местами столбцов и прочего...

Comment: @smackmychi, спасибо, сейчас как раз вспомнил, что сам раз на этом обжёгся. Поправил ответ.

Comment: @Yuri_Prime, сам тоже на этом попался. Потому что документацию читал как попало. Самое печальное - кто-то ведь оставляет подобные ответы. Я в Java новичок, и, может быть, когда-то был только такой способ получения значения ячеек.